# 3D Touch / Force Touch usage adoption rates

Tags: input, adoption

Are there any reports or analysis of the adoption and use rates of 3D Touch?

All the people around me are basically using their S series phones as if they don't have the feature, at all. But surely this can't be the general case, as I don't see any negative media commentary on its adoption.

Comment: Its a cool feature that will be widely adopted in the future by all vendors. It just gives another level of touch interaction. However, some time is needed (a couple of years) until this interaction type gets widely adopted by the mobile phone users.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the only people with a complete answer will be Apple, and they are unlikely to release that information. 3rd party apps may also have data on their own specific usage, but that won't give a complete picture.

The only quantifiable data (and it's not high quality) I have seen is from a [poll here:](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-often-do-you-use-3D-Touch-on-your-iPhone-6s-or-6s-Plus_id75527)

> HOW OFTEN DO YOU USE 3D TOUCH ON YOUR IPHONE 6S OR 6S PLUS?
>
> Just to show it off to friends and family - 
>   **33.98%
>   508 votes**
>
> I use it every now and then - **21.74%
>   325 votes**
>
> I use it all the time - **12.51%
>   187 votes**
>
> What's 3D Touch? **31.77%
>   475 votes**